# Namecoin Offline Wallet Generator

Tags: namecoin, paper-wallet

I want to keep some NMC offline. Is there a way to generate an offline wallet like bitaddress.org that I can run on a live CD, generate wallet and keep offline?

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out the python library [Coinkit](https://github.com/halfmoonlabs/coinkit) - it's for generating cryptocurrency wallets (Bitcoin, Namecoin, Litecoin, Peercoin, Primecoin, Dogecoin and a bunch of others are currently supported).

Just do "pip install coinkit".

Answer (score 0):

Someone could modify that source code to work with namecoin, but in the meantime here is a workaround:

Open namecoin-QT and copy the address you want to export the private key for into the clipboard. Then select help, debug window, and click on the console tab. In the prompt box at the bottom type:

> dumpprivkey {paste namecoin address}

This should return the private key (long number starting with a 5)
Write down the private key and put it somewhere safe. If you want to destroy the original first be sure that you have backed up ALL your private keys, then close namecoin-qt and delete your namecoin wallet.dat file.

To recover it you can use:

> importprivkey {private key}

After the import you should see the address and funds in the target wallet you are importing the key into, but it will take a bit since the namecoin client needs to look through it's whole history to determine the value on the restored address.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this site by virtual_master: http://namecoinia.org/

You can save it for offline use.

Also this utility from casascius should do the job: http://casascius.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/bitcoin-address-utility/

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://github.com/samr7/vanitygen

```
# git clone https://github.com/samr7/vanitygen
# cd vanitygen
# make
# ./vanitygen -N NAME
Difficulty: 78508
Pattern: NAME                                                                  
Address: NAMEuWT2icj3ef8HWJwetZyZbXaZUJ5hFT
Privkey: 74pxNKNpByQ2kMow4d9kF6Z77BYeKztQNLq3dSyU4ES1K5KLNiz
```

Thereafter, simple import `privkey`.